# How to build a specific GKI kernel?

Tags: android, linux, kernel

I’m a bit confused. Coming from Linux kernel development to Android I totally see the value of the “frozen” GKI ABIs. Following that, it also makes sense that the main manifest of AOSP references binary kernels instead of sources. But what I can’t figure out:

How do you build a specific GKI kernel version? And/or: How do you build kernel modules that work with a specific GKI kernel (even if built separately)?

What I’m looking for is a way to reproduce the builds byte-for-byte, e.g., in a VM. I can’t find any info how Google does it. Bonus points if anyone can tell me what’s the quickest way to achieve a kernel module build ala `make -C/lib/modules/$(uname -r) M=$PWD`. :-)